# AVFoundation not playing audio files in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have gone through all of the SpriteKit tutorials on raywenderlich.com and gotten everything to work in each of the tutorials, except the audio. I can't get any sound effects to work in any of the tutorials. For example, in this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/49697/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-2, I copied the sound files into my project, then

1) imported AVFoundation into MyScene.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

2) added three properties in MyScene.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKAction *laughSound;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKAction *owSound;
```

3) Preloaded sound effects in initWithSize in MyScene.m

```
// Add at the bottom of your initWithSize: method
// Preload whack sound effect
self.laughSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"laugh.caf" waitForCompletion:NO];
self.owSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"ow.caf" waitForCompletion:NO];

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"whack" withExtension:@"caf"];
NSError *error = nil;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

if (!self.audioPlayer) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}

[self.audioPlayer play];
```

4) Added the sound actions to the sequence in two different methods

```
// Add at bottom of popMole method, change the sequence action to:
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[easeMoveUp, setTappable, self.laughSound, self.laughAnimation, unsetTappable, easeMoveDown]];

// Add inside touchesBegan: method, change the sequence action to:
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[self.owSound, self.hitAnimation, easeMoveDown]];
```

Can anyone explain why the sound might not be playing when I run the code on my device?  Note, when I make regular iOS apps (without SpriteKit), I have been able to use AVFoundation without a problem.

Update

As suggested in the first comment, I ran a sound file using skaction alone but it didn't play the sound. The log statement ran everytime it was supposed to

```
 SKAction *sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"laugh.caf" waitForCompletion:NO];
 NSLog(@"run sound");
 [self runAction:sound];
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's the actual sound files themselves. Grab an apple system .aiff sound file and try playing those to make sure it's not some oddness with the sound export. Looking at my AVAudioPlayer manager, I also have `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>` which I believe is required to change the volume on the AVAudioPlayer object. Are you doing anything with AVAudioSession elsewhere in the project that could be causing an issue?

Comment: @CHBuckingham when I click on the sound files (which are .caf in this project) in xcode, they open in a new window with audio player and they play fine. I'm not doing anything with AVAudioSession. This is just a simple tutorial I'm following. However, as mentioned in the OP, i've done multiple SpriteKit tutorials with audio and always the same result (no sound), even though I've made non-SpriteKit ios projects that play audio perfectly with AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: The usage is confusing, I'm not sure why you're using SKActions and an instance of AVAudioPlayer both. Which leads me to think you're combining tutorial code maybe? I would do what I suggest in the first comment, playing a system sound file via the SKAction to ensure it's not the export settings, which is it is most situations.

Comment: @CHBuckingham sorry I guess I misunderstood your first comment. I tried it now (see update in OP) but sound didn't play. I don't think I'm mixing tutorial code (link's in OP). This is something that happened with every SpriteKit tutorial I've done on their site.

Answer (score 0):

If the sound file doesn't play via an SKAction, but the same sound file does play via an AVAudioPlayer in a non sprite kit project, then it is pretty much always 1 of 3 things:

1. Whatever is playing the action is not a child in the scene hierarchy.
2. The file format / export settings for the sound file are not supported by the far more restrictive SKAction.
3. The AVAudiOSession shared instance is setup incorrectly.

Without seeing all of the code of the project, I'm still betting on 1 or 2.